# How do I parse a random space-separated text file and turn into tab-separated file

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am reading a huge, machine generated, tab-separated text-file. I have made the following code below to fetch the values, but this will work only when text file is in tab separated manner, and it turns out that the **external software** is using a random amount of spaces between each field.

How do I produce code which will read the random space-separated text file into a tab separated file. My current work-around is to open the file in Microsoft Excel and re-save as tab-separated file. But this will not work properly as Excel cannot properly recognize the random amount of space delimiters. Following is the code i did for reading a **tab separated text file** in a row column format, but I need help for a solution for my machine generated file.

```
string filename = @"D:\EMS_DATA\firstfile.txt";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename)
    .Where(arg => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg)).ToArray();
string[] cols = lines[0].Trim()
    .Split(new[] {'\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

int linesss = 1;
foreach (string line in lines.Skip(1))
{
    string[] cells = line.Trim()
        .Split(new[] {'\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int counter = 0; counter < cols.Length; counter++)
    {
        string cellValue = "N/A";
        if(counter < cells.Length)
            cellValue = cells[counter];
        Console.WriteLine(
            "values at row {0} column {1} are {2} : {3}", 
            line, 
            counter, 
            cols[counter], 
            cellValue);
    }

    linesss++;
}
```

**Format of text file is**

```
firstname  lastname  salary  age
sasi   kiran    88000   32
ravi   kiran    92000   23
jafer  sharif   34000   45
kiran  bedi     45000   34
```

**UPDATE:**
The generated text-files are not in a proper format. My current work-around is to open the file in Microsoft Excel, then save it again as a tab-separated file. I need help with code that can do this for me automatically.

Comment: you'd have to explain exactly what the format of this "column row format" file is, e.g. show an example

Comment: Use the .NET TextFieldParser class.  You like its TextFieldType set to FixedWidth and its FieldWidths property.

Comment: @Marc B i have updated my question

Comment: @Hans Passant can you provide the code for TextFieldParser class

Comment: @Hans Passant i tried what you mentioned but no luck.I updated my question

Comment: Why don't you just use Regex.Match() with the pattern "(\\w+)|(\\d+)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

There's a potential problem here. If you compare a tab-separated file with one where spaces have been used instead (using your example which I assume is **exactly** the same as the machine generated file), there is no apparent pattern for spacing. See below:

```
//These have spaces
firstname  lastname  salary  age
sasi   kiran    88000   32
ravi   kiran    92000   23
jafer  sharif   34000   45
kiran  bedi     45000   34

//These have tabs
firstname   lastname    salary  age
sasi    kiran   88000   32
ravi    kiran   92000   23
jafer   sharif  34000   45
kiran   bedi    45000   34
```

Unless you can find a pattern, this essentially means that no cell can contain a space, otherwise you'll fail the split. I suggest you try to find a pattern there.

For the code itself, I took the opportunity to revamp your code a bit, and also incorporate Regex. It just makes more sense to use regex in cases like these.

**The code:**

```
        string filename = @"C:\firstfile.txt";

        //Regex objects to detect every range of spaces between 1-infinite, OR one tab.
        Regex regx = new Regex(@"[\s]+|[\t]", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        //Read all lines of a file, one line per index
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

        //Create multi-dimensional List array
        List<List<string>> sheet = new List<List<string>>();

        //Split each line in lines by column, and you end up with a multi-dimensional array.
        //Makes it look like an excel sheet. [Row][Column]
        sheet.AddRange(lines.Select(x => new List<string>(regx.Split(x).ToList())));

        //Start from rowIndex = 1, as 0 contains the headers
        for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < sheet.Count; rowIndex++)
        {
            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < sheet[rowIndex].Count; colIndex++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("values at row {0} column {1} are {2} : {3}",
                    rowIndex,
                    colIndex,
                    sheet[0][colIndex],
                    sheet[rowIndex][colIndex]
                    );
            }
        }
```

**Output**

```
values at row 1 column 0 are firstname : sasi
values at row 1 column 1 are lastname : kiran
values at row 1 column 2 are salary : 88000
values at row 1 column 3 are age : 32
values at row 2 ...
```

If it turns out that your machine generated code always puts a minimum amount of spaces between each field which is **more than** 1 space, you can have **anything less than that amount of spaces** in the actual "cells". If this turns out to be the case, modify the regex pattern like below:

**Replace this:**

```
Regex regx = new Regex(@"[\s]+|[\t]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

**With:**

```
Regex regx = new Regex(@"[\s]{2,}|[\t]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

I'd also like to mention that this is why CSV's are more popular, because those files use ";" instead of whitespace.

To write this all back into a proper tab-separated file, use the below:

```
    string filename_modified = @"C:\modifiedfile.txt";
    File.WriteAllText(filename_modified, String.Join(Environment.NewLine, sheet.Select(x => String.Join("\t", x))));
```

Comment: that i already fixed it,thats my mistake posting, but my question is how to make textfile tab serperated in order to work with this code.The text file generated are not tab seperated

Comment: Does it have to be tab separated? Can you use CSV's instead?

Comment: Also, if the issue is with unrelated software not generating tab-separated data properly, the information you provided us with is completely irrelevant.

Comment: the generated textfiles are not in a proper format.As of now what i did is i opened text file with microsoft excel in a tab separated way and then again saved as text file.Then i used above code to process. My Question is do we have a code which will do the manual process what i did above?

Comment: thanks ,let me see it,for a trial it worked like charm :)

Comment: Hey no problem. Another thing to remember is that if you need to use the index of an iteration, don't use foreach, just use the for-loop instead.